# JQuery between frames and ajax loads

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

I have a site with a main page, iframe, and multiple AJAX pages within the iframe.

Example:
`Window(main page) > iFrame > Ajax Load > Ajax Load`

I need to have JQuery available for all of these components, but the only way I have gotten this to work is to load a new instance of JQuery for the main page, the iframe, and every individual ajax load.

I have heard that you can use `parent.$()` to use JQuery from inside of an iframe, but I have also heard this can complicate selectors and I am not sure if this works at all for AJAX loads.

So, could somebody explain how I can load a single instance of JQuery and use it from inside an iFrame and any AJAX page that is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iFrame works as a separate window, so you'll either need to use the parent selector or load jQuery within the iFrame itself. Assuming the iFrame does the ajax loads, only the parent page within the iFrame will need to include the js file.